# I can not get information about the error of validation in AngularJS

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-boot, validation, spring-mvc

I have a html form with some fields which I need to validate (name, address, email and etc). And it works, but I can't pass information about validation error from `@PostMapping` method to AngularJS. The response is empty. What am I doing wrong?

Store.java - controller class

```
    @Controller
    public class Store {

        @PostMapping("/save")
        public ResponseEntity<Object> getShippingInfo(@Valid @RequestBody final User user,
                final BindingResult bindingResult) {

            Store.LOGGER.info("{}", user);

            if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
                Store.LOGGER.info("{}", "Validation failed");
                final List<String> errors = bindingResult.getAllErrors().stream()
                        .map(DefaultMessageSourceResolvable::getDefaultMessage)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());

                return new ResponseEntity<>(errors, HttpStatus.OK);
            } else {
                Store.LOGGER.info("{}", "Validation successed");
            }
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
        }
    }
```

Main.js - file with AngularJS

```
  var app = angular.module('myShoppingList', ['ngRoute', 'ngStorage']);
  //some code
  app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $location, items) {
    $scope.listCustomers;

    $scope.postFunc = function () {

      if ($scope.formCust) {
        $scope.listCustomers = this.formCust;
        $scope.formCust = {};
      }

      var urlInfo = '/save';
      var config = {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'text/plain'
        }
      };

      var dataArr = $scope.listCustomers;

      $http.post(urlInfo, dataArr, config).then(function (response) {
        $scope.postDivAvailable = true;
        $scope.postCust = response.data;
      }, function error(response) {
        $scope.postResultMessage = 'Error Status: ' + response.statusText;
        console.log('', $scope.postResultMessage);
      });

      $scope.listCustomers = [];
      $scope.result = 'Success!';
    };
  });
```

So here my output in browser console from `$scope.postResultMessage` is just empty, while from `Store.LOGGER.info("{}", errors);` I get in Eclipse console as expected:

```
[size must be between 7 and 10, invalid credit card number]
```

---

Update 1

If i'm trying to output just response to browser console I'm getting this:
[image]

Comment: The "error" binding function will only trigger when you send an HTTP status with a status code `>= 400`. Have you tried replacing your `HttpStatus.OK` with something else? Maybe "bad request"?

Comment: Looks like i have a response but without error information. I updated my post. And i just tried with HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST and it also doesn't work.

Comment: You are not sending back text/plain, but you are saying `Accept: text/plain`. You are sending back a JSON array I assume. So perhaps change your frontend conf to `Accept: application/json`. This in combination with the HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST. HTTP406 says basically that content type negotiation failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem might be that you return your errors with HTTP Status code 200. This means that front end error block is not executed (Frontend assumes everything is OK). You should set the HTTP status code to Bad Request for example.

Comment: Looks like i have a response but without error information. I updated my post. And i just tried with HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST and it also doesn't work.